# How can I return different values from a mocked method using AngularJS and Karma?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm testing ServiceA which uses ServiceB within itself.  ServiceB has a method called getData() and sometimes it returns true and sometimes it returns false.  Service A has different logic depending on whether ServiceB returns true or false and I need to test both situations.  Currently, I'm mocking Service B like this:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app', function ($provide) {
    serviceB = {
        getData: function () {
           return true;
        }
    };

    $provide.value('serviceB', serviceB);
}));
```

So how I can test what happens when serviceB returns true and then make anothter test to verify its behavior when it returns false?  Can I create the mock within the it() methods rather than in beforeEach() so that I can have the mock return different values in different test methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just mock it in your individual tests:

```
beforeEach(...)
it('test with true', inject(function (serviceB) {
    spyOn(seviceB, 'getData').and.callFake(function(){
        return true;
    });

    //... other test code

    expect(serviceB.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
it('test with false', inject(function (serviceB) {
    spyOn(seviceB, 'getData').and.callFake(function(){
        return false;
    });

    //... other test code

    expect(serviceB.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Works perfectly!

Comment: When I do something like this, I receive an error that reads: 'Error: getData has already been spied upon'